# How to find Data Abort exception function/instruction from source code?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, windows-ce, msdn

I am running an application on a device, this device can have external accessories connected to it with serial USB interface. I noticed that while unplugging the accessory from the USB port the device hangs. The serial log show that Data Abort exceptions are thrown:

> [ERROR] PID:00400003 TID:0250001A Exception 'Data Abort' (0x4): Thread-Id=0250001a(pth=bd8d2660), Proc-Id=00400002(pprc=8534a5e0) 'NK.EXE', VM-active=046b0082(pprc=bd895298) 'Osl_Spec.exe'
>
> [ERROR] PID:00400003 TID:0250001A PC=8042f520(kernel.dll+0x00014520) RA=cb33fdf0(???+0xcb33fdf0) SP=dcfffae8, BVA=00000014
>
> [ERROR] PID:00400003 TID:0250001A Exception 'Raised Exception' (0x116): Thread-Id=0250001a(pth=bd8d2660), Proc-Id=00400002(pprc=8534a5e0) 'NK.EXE', VM-active=046b0082(pprc=bd895298) 'Osl_Spec.exe'
>
> [ERROR] PID:00400003 TID:0250001A PC=eff0e4d8(k.coredll.dll+0x0001e4d8) RA=80429648(kernel.dll+0x0000e648) SP=dcfff1fc, BVA=ffffffff
>
> [ERROR] PID:00400003 TID:0250001A Exception 'Data Abort' (0x4): Thread-Id=0250001a(pth=bd8d2660), Proc-Id=00400002(pprc=8534a5e0) 'NK.EXE', VM-active=046b0082(pprc=bd895298) 'Osl_Spec.exe'
>
> [ERROR] PID:00400003 TID:0250001A PC=8042f520(kernel.dll+0x00014520) RA=cb33fdf0(???+0xcb33fdf0) SP=dcfffad4, BVA=00000014
>
> [ERROR] PID:00400003 TID:0250001A Exception 'Raised Exception' (0x116): Thread-Id=0250001a(pth=bd8d2660), Proc-Id=00400002(pprc=8534a5e0) 'NK.EXE', VM-active=046b0082(pprc=bd895298) 'Osl_Spec.exe'
>
> [ERROR] PID:00400003 TID:0250001A PC=eff0e4d8(k.coredll.dll+0x0001e4d8) RA=80429648(kernel.dll+0x0000e648) SP=dcfff1e8, BVA=ffffffff

I want get to the part of source code that is responsible for these exceptions. I have read a few articles which suggest using MAP files of the driver file shown next to RA(return address) but in my errors I see "???" instead of a driver file name. OSL_SPEC.exe is my application. Kindly suggest how I can get to the source of the problem in code.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to do that but first you need to have compiled your file with debug flag. 
If you have done that, and your bug is reproductible, then you can run your file in debug mode with stop point in your code (on linux you can do that with `gdb`, on windows it may exist this kind of tool). 
If your bug is non reprouctible, you should find a way to catch exception in the main function and return the call stack. Then use a copy of `addr2line` on windows to find the function that cause the exception.

I noticed that your logs talks about `kernel.dll` and `k.coredll.dll`. Are these file part of your project (as lib) or your VM? 
you should take an eye on these file (+ adress offset) if they are part of your project.